# Recover files from NQ Vault after uninstalling it

Tags: data-recovery, nqvault

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab and NQ Vault app, storing some files, then I uninstalled it. Now I realized I can't recover the files from it.

I've tried reinstalling the app, but it did not give me the option of restoring previously stored files. I don't have any backup either.

How can I recover my files from NQ vault after uninstalling the app?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the folder in the internal storage. It is typically under android folder. Enable the "show hidden files" option. After that, begin your search.
The folder of the vault can also be under `data` folder.

Comment: If the folder is "under the data folder", it's gone (deleted when the app was uninstalled). The only place where it *could* have survived would be on the SD card *outside* of `Android/data` – but what sense would it make for a vault to store its stuff in public space? So I'm rather afraid the data is gone for good.